# RegExp Javascript HEX Colors Light and Dark

Tags: javascript, regex, colors, hex

I want to use a regular expression to replace the first F of each of the three hex sets that make up a hex color with an E.

FFFFFF would become EFEFEF

FEFEFE would become EEEEEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
str = str.replace(/F(?=[A-F0-9](?:[A-F0-9]{2}){0,2}$)/g, 'E');
```

Pattern details:

```
F
(?=         # lookahead assertion: means "followed by"
            # the trick is to use the relative position to the end of the string
    [A-F0-9]  # an hexadecimal character    
    (?:[A-F0-9]{2}){0,2} # an even number of hexadecimal characters
$                        # until the end
)           # close the lookahead assertion.
```

Note that all that is in the lookahead is only checked, but is not a part of the match result. This is the reason why the replacement string is only `E`.

Comment: Yup, works perfect. I was going completely the wrong direction with my code. Thanks.

Comment: `dadsaF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0asddsa`

Comment: Fails on AFFAAA. The second pattern will match, but it will be the first match so the $1 gets the wrong value. At least I think thats why it fails.

Comment: @user3642891: and what do you want to obtain with `AFFAAA` ?

Comment: Ok, I guess I assumed some things in my original question. Basically I am going to receive a hex color code. They are 6 digit hex numbers, but I calculate them in a string of 6 characters. I just want to change every other F in to an E. So FEFEFE would become EEEEEE and AFFAAA would become AFEAAA. I only care about the first F in each of the 3 sets of two digit hex numbers. I hope that is more clear. :(

Comment: @user3642891: OK, I have udapted my answer for these new informations.

Comment: Could you add an explanation? Your answer is incomplete.

Comment: Well done. Thats like the advanced stage of advanced. So many techniques applied I had no chance being somewhat new to regexp. Thanks for your patience with my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the function that would do that would be triggered by an event such as onClick, or whatsoever.
Why do you not simply do a function like this (pseudo-code) ?

```
if (colour == FFFFFF)
colour = EFEFEF;
else if (colour == FEFEFE)
colour = EEEEEE;
```

Comment: It needs to be dynamic. I wont know what color will be chosen, but I will never want each hex block to start with an F. The untested idea is it will limit the brightness of the color by reducing the amount RGB allowed.